# initComponents bindingGroup error

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't know what's the problem here. Any suggestions?

I'm a student in a group. This issue seems that only affects me.

Thank you,
Ramon.

/**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */

[image]

```
public class ManteSocis extends JPanel {

private static final String FALTEN_DADES = "Hi falta el nom i/o el primer cognom";
private static final String ID_NEGATIU = "L'identificador ha de ser mes gran que zero";
private static final String FORMAT_ERRONI = "Format erroni";
private static final String AFICIO_EXISTENT = "L'aficio ja afegida";

private final GestorPersistencia db;
private final FormListener formListener1 = new FormListener();
private DefaultListModel <String> modelLlista;

private JTextField calNetejar[];

public ManteSocis(GestorPersistencia db) {
    this.db=db;

    initComponents();

    calNetejar=new JTextField[]{idTextField,nomTextField,primerCognomTextField,segonCognomTextField,aficioTextField};

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

    try{
        list = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections.observableList(Collections.checkedList(db.obtenirSocisOrdenatsPerId(),model.Soci.class));
        try{
            listAficions = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections.observableList(Collections.checkedList(db.obtenirSocisOrdenatsPerId(),model.Soci.class));
            masterScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            masterTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
            deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            detailScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            detailTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
            saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            refreshButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            aficioTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            newButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            suprimeixButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            afegeixButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            idTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            nomTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            primerCognomTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            segonCognomTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            aficionsList = new javax.swing.JList<String>();
            jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            FormListener formListener1 = new FormListener();

        }catch(UtilitatPersistenciaException e){
            Util.tractaExcepcio(this,e);
        }

    }catch(UtilitatPersistenciaException e){
        Util.tractaExcepcio(this,e);
    }

    masterTable.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, list, masterTable);
    org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${id}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Id");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${nom}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Nom");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${cognom1}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Cognom1");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${cognom2}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Cognom2");
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
    bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
    jTableBinding.bind();
    masterScrollPane.setViewportView(masterTable);

    deleteButton.setText("Esborra soci");

    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), deleteButton, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    deleteButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty eLProperty = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.aficions}");
    jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, eLProperty, detailTable);
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ObjectProperty.create());
    columnBinding.setColumnName("Aficio");
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
    jTableBinding.setSourceUnreadableValue(java.util.Collections.emptyList());
    bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
    jTableBinding.bind();
    detailScrollPane.setViewportView(detailTable);

    saveButton.setText("Grava");
    saveButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    refreshButton.setText("Refresca");
    refreshButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Manteniment socis");
    jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

    jLabel2.setText("Aficio:");

    newButton.setText("Nou soci");
    newButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    suprimeixButton.setText("-");
    suprimeixButton.setToolTipText("Esborra l'aficio seleccionada");

    binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, aficionsList, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement!=null}"), suprimeixButton, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

    suprimeixButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    afegeixButton.setText("+");
    afegeixButton.setToolTipText("Afegeixi l'aficio del quadre de text");
    afegeixButton.addActionListener(formListener1);

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setText("Alta de socis");
    jLabel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

    jLabel4.setText("Id:");

    jLabel5.setText("Nom:");

    jLabel6.setText("Primer cognom:");

    jLabel7.setText("Segon cognom:");

    aficionsList.setModel(modelLlista=new DefaultListModel<String>());
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(aficionsList);

    jLabel8.setText("Aficions");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(idTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(nomTextField)
                        .addComponent(primerCognomTextField)
                        .addComponent(segonCognomTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 136, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(aficioTextField))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(afegeixButton)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(suprimeixButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 231, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(newButton))
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 636, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(idTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(nomTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(primerCognomTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(segonCognomTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(aficioTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(afegeixButton)
                        .addComponent(suprimeixButton))
                    .addGap(0, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(newButton)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 430, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(deleteButton)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(detailScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 231, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap())))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(refreshButton)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(saveButton)
            .addGap(9, 9, 9))
    );

    layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {refreshButton, saveButton});

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 133, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(detailScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(deleteButton)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(refreshButton)
                .addComponent(saveButton))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    bindingGroup.bind();
}

// Code for dispatching events from components to event handlers.

private class FormListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
    FormListener() {}
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == deleteButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == saveButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == refreshButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.refreshButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == newButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.newButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == suprimeixButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.suprimeixButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == afegeixButton) {
            ManteSocis.this.afegeixButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }
}// </editor-fold>                        


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void refreshButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try {
        db.anullaCanvis();
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(db.obtenirSocisOrdenatsPerId());
    } catch (UtilitatPersistenciaException ex) {
        Util.tractaExcepcio(this, ex);
    }
}                                             

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
      int sel=masterTable.getSelectedRow();

      if(sel!=-1){
          try {
              db.eliminar((model.Soci)list.get(sel));
              list.remove(sel);


          } catch (UtilitatPersistenciaException ex) {
              Util.tractaExcepcio(this, ex);
          }
      }
      else{
          Util.avisa(this, Util.CAP_FILA_SEL);
      }

}                                            

private void newButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    int id;
    String nom, primerCognom, segonCognom;

    try{
        id = new Integer(idTextField.getText());
        if(id<0){
            Util.avisa(this,ID_NEGATIU);
        }else{
            nom=nomTextField.getText().trim();
            primerCognom=primerCognomTextField.getText().trim();
            segonCognom=segonCognomTextField.getText().trim();

            if(nom.isEmpty()||primerCognom.isEmpty()){
                Util.avisa(this,FALTEN_DADES);
            }
            else {
                try{
                    List<String> aficions;
                    Soci s=db.nouSociTemporal(id);
                    s.setNom(nom);
                    s.setCognom1(primerCognom);
                    s.setCognom2(segonCognom);
                    aficions=s.getAficions();
                    for(Object cadena:modelLlista.toArray()){  // afegim les aficions
                        aficions.add(""+cadena);
                    }
                    db.inserir(s);
                    list.add(s);
                    netejaCamps();
                    modelLlista.removeAllElements();

                    // situar el cursor de la taula sobre l'element afegit

                    int x =list.size()-1;

                    masterTable.setRowSelectionInterval(x, x);
                    masterTable.scrollRectToVisible(masterTable.getCellRect(x, 0, true));


                }catch(UtilitatPersistenciaException e){
                    Util.avisa(this, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        Util.avisa(this,FORMAT_ERRONI);
    }



}                                         

private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        db.gravaCanvis();
    } catch (UtilitatPersistenciaException ex) {
        try {
            Util.tractaExcepcio(this, ex);
            db.anullaCanvis();
        } catch (UtilitatPersistenciaException e) {
            Util.tractaExcepcio(this, e);
        }

    }
}                                          


private void afegeixButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String aux = aficioTextField.getText().trim();

    if(modelLlista.contains(aux)){
        Util.avisa(this,AFICIO_EXISTENT);
    }else{
        modelLlista.addElement(aux);
    }

}                                             

private void suprimeixButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    String aux = (String)aficionsList.getSelectedValue();

    if(aux==null){
        Util.avisa(this,Util.CAP_FILA_SEL);
    }
    else{
       modelLlista.removeElement(aux);
    }    

}                                               

private void netejaCamps(){
    for(JTextField t:calNetejar){
        t.setText("");
    }

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton afegeixButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField aficioTextField;
private javax.swing.JList<String> aficionsList;
private javax.swing.JButton deleteButton;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane detailScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTable detailTable;
private javax.swing.JTextField idTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private java.util.List<model.Soci> list;
private java.util.List<model.Soci> listAficions;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane masterScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JTable masterTable;
private javax.swing.JButton newButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField nomTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField primerCognomTextField;
private javax.swing.JButton refreshButton;
private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField segonCognomTextField;
private javax.swing.JButton suprimeixButton;
private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
// End of variables declaration                   


public static JInternalFrame perMDI(GestorPersistencia db){
    JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(new ManteSocis(db));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    return frame;

}
```

}

Comment: Post your code as text, not image.

Comment: there´s an error in your code

Answer (score 0):

A new installation of NetBeans has resolved the problem.

Thank you,